# Vulkan VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED (18.04, Radeon HD 6520G)

Tags: 18.04, radeon, vulkan

I am trying to get vulkan working on my old AMD laptop

OS:
ubuntu 18.04

Hardware:
AMD A6-3420M APU with integrated Radeon HD 6520G

Radeon HD 6520G details (https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-HD-6520G.55734.0.html)
    Seris:      Radeon HD 6000M 
    Codename:   Llano
    Architecture:   Terascale 2

It is difficult to tell if this hardware is supported from the chart  here: 
https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/vulkan

After following these instructions( https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install libvulkan1 mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils
```

and rebooting, I get this:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' $

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

$ vulkaninfo
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.70

/build/vulkan-Kbdbga/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:2700: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

Answer (score -1):

The [wikipedia page for AMD GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units) clearly lists *Terascale 2* as NOT supporting vulkan.
The ammount of rebranding and renming of graphics components makes this quite the hunt.

For those in similar "does my AMD card support vulkan?" waters:

1.) identify your card from the commandline

```
$lspci |grep 'VGA'
```

2.) Search the GPU specs at a site such as [notebookcheck.net](https://www.notebookcheck.net) and find its 'architecture' or 'chipset'

3.) look up the chipset on the  [wikipedia page for AMD GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units)